# SQL JOIN with OR

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to do the following in SQL?

```
SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON (col1=col2 OR TRIM(col1)=TRIM(col2))
```

Or:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 USING (col1 OR col2)
```

Comment: Well, have you tried it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use arbitrary logic in a join. So, to answer your question: Yes, you can use a disjunction ("OR") in a join. That said, in your specific example, your logic is <s>a tautology -- it's always true -- so it won't achieve anything</s> redundant.

You don't have to join on equality, either. For example, we can mimic windowing functions by comparing magnitude:

```
select    greatest.id,
          greatest.val
from      someTable greatest
left join someTable greater
on        greater.id  = greatest.id
and       greater.val > greatest.val
where     greater.id is null;
```

While my above example is pretty common, I've found it *very* rare to use non-conjunctive joins, per your question. However, it can certainly be done.

Comment: It's not a tautology; it is redundant.  `col1` might not be equal to `col2`.